# Validar que exista archivo cargado en formulario antes de insertar en Base de Datos

Tags: php, formularios

Necesito un poco de ayuda con la validación de un formulario que contiene un input "FILE"

```
<form action="guardarTicket.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="file" id="imagenTicket" class="form-control form-control-sm" 
        name="imagenTicket[]" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple">
        <div class="input-group margin15">
            <input type="text" id="nombreTicket" class="form-control" name="nombreTicket" aria- 
            describedby="basic-addon1" aria-label="Ticket" placeholder="Nombre del ticket">
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="centrar-contenido">
         <input type="submit" id="botonGuardarTicket" class="btn btn-secondary fw-light" 
         name="botonGuardarTicket" value="GUARDAR TICKET DE PAGO" />
     </div>
 </form>
```

En el archivo guardarTicket.php la validación me truena el código, lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
if( $_FILES["imagenTicket"]["tmp_name"] != "" ) { // También lo valido con NULL
    echo "Si funciona"; // Cargara a DB o Disco
} else {
    echo "No funciona"; // No cargara a DB o Disco
}
```

Mi problema es que no valida correctamente o no se como hacerlo correctamente, por ejemplo si el input FILE lo mando con una imagen muestra el echo "Si funciona"; // Cargara a DB o Disco pero si lo mando vacío también marca echo "Si funciona"; // Cargara a DB o Disco es decir se va por el TRUE del ciclo if en cualquier caso ¿Cómo lo valido correctamente?
Ya intente con [type], [name] con [tmp_name] o poniendo el if de manera más compleja con doble condicion en el if.
Es una replica de código que implementare en otro código más complejo (Por si ven que le falta un poco de información en el guardarTicket.php lo puse solo de ejemplo realmente) básicamente solo necesito que limite a ciertas extensiones y tamaño de imagen ¡Espero me haya explicado y me puedan explicar un poco como valido en lado servidor!

La validación que necesito hacer es:

```
foreach($_FILES["imagenTicket"]['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
        if($_FILES[ 'imagenTicket' ][ 'type' ] [ $key ] == 'image/png' || $_FILES[ 'imagenTicket' ][ 'type' ] [ $key ] == 'image/jpeg' || $_FILES[ 'imagenTicket' ][ 'size' ] [ $key ] <= 500000) {
            $nombreTicket = $_POST['nombreTicket'] . ' ' . $numeroTicket ++;
            $filename = $_FILES["imagenTicket"]["name"][$key]; //Obtenemos el nombre original del archivo
            $source = $_FILES["imagenTicket"]["tmp_name"][$key];  //Obtenemos un nombre temporal del archivo
            $imagenTicket = addslashes( file_get_contents( $_FILES['imagenTicket'] ['tmp_name'] [$key] ) ); // Obtenemos la imagen del archivo
            $stmt_insertar_imagenTicket = "INSERT INTO imagenes ( imagenes_nombre, imagenes_imagen ) VALUES ( '$nombreTicket','$imagenTicket' )";
            $t_insertar_imagenTicket = mysqli_query( $mysql_conexion, $stmt_insertar_imagenTicket );
        } else {
            echo "No se cargo el ticket de pago a la base de datos el formato o tamaño de la imagen no se acepto";
        }  
    }
```

Tomando en cuenta que son varias imagenes las posibles a subir necesito que se valide que sean formato png, jpg, jpeg y de X tamaño, entonces intente hacerlo con un foreach, funciona pero sin embargo no valida lo de la extensión y el tamaño, ademas de la imagen se guardar inputs TEXT, NUMBER y DATE y la imagen, como menciono guarda todo pero no valida, mi logica esta mal ¡Espero me puedas ayudar!

Answer (score 1):

Amigo puedes comprobar si tu formulario se envió, luego contar cuantas imágenes se enviaron y si es mayor a 0 esa cantidad entonces ya decides que hacer con tus imágenes.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['botonGuardarTicket'])) { // También lo valido con NULL

    //Capturar la ruta de imagenes
    $imagesTmp[] = $_FILES["imagenTicket"]["tmp_name"];

    //Contar rutas de imagenes enviadas
    $countImagesTmp = count($imagesTmp);

    //Capturar tipo de imagenes
    $imagesType[] = $_FILES["imagenTicket"]["type"];

    //Contar tipos de imagenes enviados
    $countImagesType = count($imagesType);

    //Capturar nombre de imagenes
    $imagesName[] = $_FILES["imagenTicket"]["name"];

    //Contar nombres de imagenes enviadas
    $countImagesName = count($imagesName);

    //Revisar que el total de rutas de imagenes enviadas sea mayor a 0
    if($countImagesTmp > 0){
        for($i=0; $i < $countImagesTmp; $i++) { 
        print_r($imagesTmp[$i]); 
        }
    }else{
        echo 'No se enviaron imagenes';
    }

    //Revisar que el total de tipos de imagenes enviadas sea mayor a 0
    if($countImagesType > 0){
        for($i=0; $i < $countImagesType; $i++) { 
        print_r($imagesType[$i]); 
        }
    }else{
        echo 'No se enviaron imagenes';
    }

    //Revisar que el total de nombres de imagenes enviadas sea mayor a 0
    if($countImagesName > 0){
        for($i=0; $i < $countImagesName; $i++) { 
        print_r($imagesName[$i]); 
        }
    }else{
        echo 'No se enviaron imagenes';
    }

} else {
    
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>TestingPage</title>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">
        <style type="text/css">
     
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <input type="file" id="imagenTicket" class="form-control form-control-sm" 
                name="imagenTicket[]" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple">
                <div class="input-group margin15">
                    <input type="text" id="nombreTicket" class="form-control" name="nombreTicket" aria- 
                    describedby="basic-addon1" aria-label="Ticket" placeholder="Nombre del ticket">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="centrar-contenido">
                <input type="submit" id="botonGuardarTicket" class="btn btn-secondary fw-light" 
                name="botonGuardarTicket" value="GUARDAR TICKET DE PAGO" />
            </div>
        </form>
        <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/js/all.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eso es para el caso de validar que realmente se subió alguna imagen a PHP pero en caso que...  ¿También necesite validar tipo de imagen y tamaño?
Estuve investigando un poco en internet pero también me pasa lo mismo, que se va por el TRUE por así decirlo no respeta la condicional IF

Comment: Por ejemplo acabo de usar tu respuesta, funciona, le puse un echo $countImages dentro del if anidado y me regresa un 1 = TRUE supongo por eso siempre se va por TRUE

Comment: Exacto 1 siempre será = TRUE, editare mi respuesta para responder a tu pregunta

Comment: Creo que no me explique, ¿Cómo llevamos esto a un foro creo? Espero me puedas ayudar... En mi codigo necesito que valide de la siguiente manera.. editare mi pregunta para que puedas revisar